# How can I tighten my shower head so it doesn't askew and move to the side

Tags: bathroom, shower

I'm struggling to fix a shower head holder that seems to have loosened so that its askew when placed on top. No difference in position from pressure of turning it on. Any advice on how to deal with this problem please. Thanks! - Larry

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those freaking things are the worst.  I hope someone has an idea besides "replace it".

Comment: It appears the nut on the handle controls position. Perhaps tighten or loosen it a bit. That said, I've had to resort to a work-around, such as adding an elastic band cut from bicycle inner-tube, over the arm of the holder, to increase friction. And, yes, these shower spray holder do not seem to hold position well.